# Removing iframe white space around videos?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I get rid of this extra white space that iframes create? I am using a reference to a web app but, as far as I know, it should stretch to any 16:9 aspect ratio window. This isn't happening though. It seems this happens with other videos too, but the sides are often transparent. Is there a way I can do that here? Thanks

[image]

HTML:

```
<body background="images/Background.png">
    <iframe id="primaryVideo" src="http://54.202.201.116/app/5/">
        <p> Your browser does not support iframes. </p>
    </iframe>
    <button id="restart" left="1%">Start Over</button>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#videoWrapper{
  height: 100%;
}

#primaryVideo{
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
div{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Make your iframe smaller? (width/height styles) Or are you wanting the video to be bigger?

Comment: cant help without seeing code

Comment: @abney317 I do want the video to fit the frame, but even if i make the width/height smaller there's always at least some white space.

Comment: @JoeWarner that's all the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the layout of that address and found the real location of the video. I applied the styles suggested from this old but still relevant [article](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php). It's 100% responsive. If you don't want it as big as the viewport, adjust the width of `div.frame` accordingly.

**Demo 1** is the actual video in an iframe, **Demo 2** is the site the has the video within the iframe. The player in Demo 2 looks like videoJS plugin so if you play the video through that, then the dimensions are up to the site which is still responsive. You can't see it functioning on SO because the site in question does not support https. Check it out at this [Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/xwBEt9bv8UP4mr29D5ip/).

### Demo 1

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
  <iframe src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.tapmedialabs/tap_media_intro_video_v8.mp4' width='100%' height='100%' allowfullscreen frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</div>
```

### Demo 2 see [Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/xwBEt9bv8UP4mr29D5ip/) for a functioning demo

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
  <iframe src='https://54.202.201.116/app/5/' width='100%' height='100%' allowfullscreen frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for doing all this. I need the web app to work, so demo 2 the relevant one here. 
When I try this code with the native size of the video (960x540), it has the white space which I also see on the Plunk. It can be minimized, and the white space will go away, but because you are able to tap the video, it needs to stay 960x540. 
So, when I try to make the iframe EXACTLY 960x540, it forces the video to be smaller.
My only option is to make it slightly bigger than 960x540, which results in that ugly white area. Anyway to get rid of it or make it transparent? I tried `background-color`

Comment: To clarify, the reason it needs to stay that size is because it operates using XML background data that relies on 960x540

Comment: When expanded on my 1366x768 screen its [1140x627](https://imgur.com/1AeYNUn)(if you include the extra space below it's about 678px). When you resize it it jumps to the next breakpoint, it looks as if the media queries (or whatever viewport resizing they use) are not contiguous. I'm not sure how you can control that behavior unless you own that website or if that website has an API.

Comment: Thanks that helped me find the problem. I do have access to the app website if that's what you mean, I asked a better question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523986/modifying-bootstrap-breakpoints-for-iframes